# How to test deeplink with JEST?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a pagination component in our app, and our app working on deep links.
I want to test a scenario where I have ULR like this `www.test.com` and after clicking the next button in the Pagination component the URL looks like this `www.test.com&page=1&drc=next`

How can I handle this in React testing library? :)